# R Nested Foreach Parallelization not Working

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I'm having some trouble getting some nested `foreach` loops to run in parallel. Here's the situation:

This program essentially performs hypothesis tests using different numbers of observations and different levels of statistical significance. I have four nested foreach loops. The item `data.structures` is a list of matrices on which the tests are performed. There are two different lists I'm using for `data.structures`. One list contains 243 matrices (the small list), and the other contains 19,683 (the large list).

```
number.observations = c(50,100,250,500,1000)
significance.levels = c(.001,.01,.05,.1,.15)

require(foreach)
require(doParallel)

cl = makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(cl)
results = foreach(data=data.structures,.inorder=FALSE,.combine='rbind') %:%
    foreach(iter=1:iterations,.inorder=FALSE,.combine='rbind') %:%
    foreach(number.observations=observations,.inorder=FALSE,.combine='rbind') %:%
    foreach(alpha=significance.levels,.inorder=FALSE,.combine='rbind') %dopar% {
  #SOME FUNCTIONS HERE
}
```

When I use the small list of matrices for `data.structures`, I can see all of the cores being fully utilized (100 percent CPU usage) in Windows' Resource Monitor with six threads each for eight processes, and the job completes as expected in a much shorter amount of time. When I change, however, to the larger list of matrices, the processes are initiated and can be seen in the Processes section of the Resource Monitor. Each of the eight processes shows three threads each with no CPU action. The total CPU usage is approximately 12 percent.

I'm new to parallelization with R. Even if I simplify the problem and the functions, I'm still only able to get the program to run in parallel with the small list. From my own reading, I'm wondering if this is an issue with workload distribution. I've included the `.inorder = FALSE` option to try and work around this to no avail. I'm fairly certain that this program is a good candidate for parallelization because it performs the same task hundreds of thousands of times and the loops don't depend on previous values.

Any help is tremendously appreciated!

Comment: I suspect you're running out of memory, and your machine is thrashing. Does the resource monitor tell you how much memory is used?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @SteveWeston I opened the Resource Monitor and reran the program, and memory usage peaks at only 21 percent of physical memory for the first few minutes. Is it possible that the memory would run out at some point in the future that I haven't yet reached but the system is already affected by it?

Comment: I would expect the memory usage on the master to increase through the course of the loop, but if you're only using 21 percent of memory then it doesn't sound like a memory problem. I'll think about it, but it would help if you could provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

similar issues happened in my code too.

```
y= foreach(a= seq(1,500,1),.combine='rbind') %:% 
    foreach(b = seq(1,10,1), .combine='rbind') %:%
    foreach(c = seq(1,20,1), .combine='rbind' ) %:% 
    foreach (d = seq(1,50,1), .combine='rbind' ) %do% {
        data.frame(a,b,c,d)
    }
```

A very simple nested foreach parallel loops, it can be executed, but just not in parallel style.